# How can i pass a list of objects to a method which can not change the property of an object?

Tags: c#, list

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var users = new List<User>();
        users.Add(new User { Id = 0, Score = 1 });
        users.Add(new User { Id = 1, Score = 1 });

        Func1(users, 2);
        Func1(new List<User>(users), 3);
        Func1(users.AsReadOnly().ToList(), 4);

        Func2(ref users, 5);
    }
    static void Func1(List<User> u, int q) { u[0].Score = q; }
    static void Func2(ref List<User> u, int q) { u[0].Score = q; }
}
class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

I don't want the "Score" property to be changed in `Func1` or `Func2`. The "Score" property can only be changed in the `Main()` method. How to do it?

Comment: You cannot be partially mutable. If you want to prevent changing the class into methods you have to make it immutable somehow (readonly members, struct, whatever suits you) but that will prevent changes on that class everywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interfaces.

Create an IUser interface that User implements and give it a  property Score with only a getter, not a setter. Make the functions take lists of IUser instead of User.

Main will create the User, so be able to modify the score, whereas Func1 and Func2 will only have access to the getter, and not be able to modify it.

Comment: There, a perfect use of interface. Expose only what you want :)

Comment: Honestly I'm surprised nobody else answered this in the 10 minutes before I got here.

Comment: I upvoted, but then tried [something](http://tpcg.io/JVAr9v) and I managed to change a property of the `IUser` in another method.

Comment: @Rafalon well of course if you successfully cast to a  type that exposes a setter then you will be able to modify it.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 yeah obviously. Well I suppose if I don't want to change a property, I can simply avoid using `=` with it too ^^

Comment: @Rafalon similarly, if you used reflection you would have been able to change it. However, once you start doing that you are breaking the documented interface, and so if things stop working it's your fault, not the API designers fault :)

Comment: @RB. Yup, I usually don't do that (hopefully!) but just wondered if it would work, as I wasn't really sure if using `as` would create a copy or not, and turns out it doesn't

Comment: If we were truly caring about data integrity we wouldn't be passing a list of users around anyway, we'd be using an IScoreProvider or something like that which completely abstracted the view away from the underlying model.

Comment: @CallumBradbury, I am very grateful to you for the proposed solution with the interface. But could you help me to compose google request to read an example ("without passing list" and "IScoreProvider")?